# ToolbarContent: add a .disabled(Bool) method

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, toolbar

I've created a custom `ToolbarContent` for common buttons, such as Save, Edit, Cancel, etc...

For example:

```
import SwiftUI

public struct SaveToolbarItem: ToolbarContent {
    private let placement: ToolbarItemPlacement
    private let action: () -> Void

    public init(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement = .confirmationAction,
                action: @escaping () -> Void = {}) {
        self.placement = placement
        self.action = action
    }

    public var body: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(placement: placement) {
            Button(
                "Save"
            ) {
                action()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At call site:

```
        .toolbar {            
            SaveToolbarItem() {
                 // some code for the Action
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
            .disabled(true) // Value of type 'SaveToolbarItem' has no member 'disabled'
        }
```

However, I'm getting the following error while trying to use `isDisabled` method:

> Value of type 'SaveToolbarItem' has no member 'disabled'

How can I mitigate this error? E.g. maybe define `disabled` only on my custom types of `ToolbarContent`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place it inside, like

```
public var body: some ToolbarContent {
    ToolbarItem(placement: placement) {
        Button(
            "Save"
        ) {
            action()
        }
        .disabled(true)     // << here !!
    }
}
```

*of course parameter for `disabled` is expected to be passed in.

**Updated:** Here is possible approach with built-in `disabled` modifier.

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

[image: demo]

```
public struct SaveToolbarItem: ToolbarContent {
    private let placement: ToolbarItemPlacement
    private let action: () -> Void

    private var enabled = true

    public init(placement: ToolbarItemPlacement = .confirmationAction,
                action: @escaping () -> Void = {}) {
        self.placement = placement
        self.action = action
    }

    public var body: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(placement: placement) {
            Button(
                "Save"
            ) {
                action()
            }
            .disabled(!enabled)
        }
    }

    func disabled(_ flag: Bool) -> Self {
        var newItem = self
        newItem.enabled = !flag
        return newItem
    }
}
```